# Tidysynth error -- Please specify only one treated unit

Tags: r, statistics

I am trying to calculate a Synthetic control using the tidysynth package. I'm fairly new to the package and the data but here is my code:

```
#Import data
synth <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FDobkin/coal_paper/main/synth_data.csv")

#Convert year to date
synth$year <- strptime(synth$year, format = "%Y")


synth_out <- synth %>%
  synthetic_control(
    outcome=saleprice,
    unit=fips,
    time=year,
    i_unit=47145,
    i_time=2009-10-19,
    generate_placebos=T
  ) %>%
  generate_predictor(
    time_window=2000-10-19:2009-10-19,
    population = pop,
    white = white_p,
    age = age65p_p,
    rucc = rucc_code,
    income = median_income,
    unemploy = unemprate,
    laborforce = lfrate
  ) %>%
  generate_weights(optimization_window = 2000-10-19:2009-10-19, # time to use in the optimization task
                   margin_ipop = .02,sigf_ipop = 7,bound_ipop = 6 # optimizer options
  )

%>%
  generate_control()
```

The error is:

```
Error in synth_method(treatment_unit_covariates = treatment_unit_covariates,  : 
  
 Please specify only one treated unit.
```

The error seems to becoming from the generate_weights() statement. I am specifying the specific county that is receiving the treatment in the synthetic_control() statement. What is the error noting is wrong?

Comment: I had the same problem and managed to solve it by wrapping the dates in as.Date().